# How to add videoPlayer as an subview?

Tags: iphone

Hello I am facing an problem related to adding subview;
I am following the Code:

```cpp
        NSString *urlStr  = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"http:x/iphone0.m3u8"];
        NSURL *videoURL   = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        MPMoviePlayerController *iVideoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:videoURL];
        [self.view addSubview:iVideoPlayer.view ];  

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
             iVideoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(353,258,320,240);
        }
        else
        {
             iVideoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(156,96,168,148);
        }                   
        [iVideoPlayer play];
```

In this code I like to add an video player as an subview . I have successfully add the videoPlayer.but problem is that during the video playing ,if i click on the specified area (CGRectMake(353,258,320,240);the video stop. I like apply the videoPlayer Function (next,Pause,Volume up/Down)which are not done .
How to resolve this .?

Comment: Did the below answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You have some options for the control style of your MPMoviePlayerController instance.  By setting the controlStyle property to one of the following options, you can enable certain player controls (like pause, play, etc).

```
MPMovieControlStyleNone,
MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded,
MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen,
MPMovieControlStyleDefault
```

The descriptions for the above styles can be found here: [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here is an example of how to set this property.

```
[iVideoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded]
```